# PHP REST api: Advice on who to POST image file

Tags: php, rest, file, upload

Ive being following this tutorial on vanilla phpRest api, so far so good, but now i want to add, images to the posts(not included in the tutorial), I'm no experto obviously, I think the content-Type in the headers prevent me from sending another thing than json, (that's the tutorial's headers).
should i turn the file into json somehow? or should i change the content-Type?, i wan to use this api with React, i want to do it php/mysql because of my shared hosting.

```
<?php 
  // Headers
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Content-Type,Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Authorization, X-Requested-With');

  include_once '../../config/Database.php';
  include_once '../../models/Post.php';

  // Instantiate DB & connect
  $database = new Database();
  $db = $database->connect();

  // Instantiate blog post object
  $post = new Post($db);

  // Get raw posted data
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

  $post->title = $data->title;
  $post->body = $data->body;
  $post->author = $data->author;
  $post->category_id = $data->category_id;

  // Create post
  if($post->create()) {
    echo json_encode(
      array('message' => 'Post Created')
    );
  } else {
    echo json_encode(
      array('message' => 'Post Not Created')
    );
  }
?>
```

Comment: usually files and images sent as link path from stored data in database, 
if you want to send image as stream , i think you gonna read the file with file_get_content() and use stream_context_create(), and may be some base64 encodig stuff

Comment: im very novice in this matter, i want to store the image in a folder and create the entry in the database, should I send 2 separated requests one with pure json to populate the database and one with the file to process it and save it to the folder? that would work but is the correct method?

Comment: usually you upload image via form submission , then you will save it to the storage on you server and take the url after you save the file and save the URL /Path in the Database,
after that you may need to send the image to - for example -a mobile app using an API,
you will get the stored image path from the database. and send it to the App using API

Comment: i could right a full answer if that was not clear, and i advice you to use framework like Slim to handle API, it will help you through many things,
it is a micro framework for API only so it can work separately away from the core of your project

Comment: I think I got a clearer perspective I was trying to process the image file and the database entry in the same endpoint, it didn't occur to me that it could be done in 2 steps, that makes more sense. thanks Mohammed.

Comment: that is OK bro,  any time :) .